# Sonar Bug: Boxed value is unboxed and then again reboxed

Tags: java, sonarqube, boxing, unboxing

I am unable to figure out where the boxed value is unboxed and again
reboxed in below sample piece of code. Can some one pls help me in
fixing this sonar bug.

```java
List<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<>();
Float hundred = 100F;
Float zero = 0F;
String []stringFloatValues= new String[]{1.2,3.44,5.66};

for(String stringFloat: stringFloatValues){
    Float value = NumberUtils.isParsable(stringFloat)
           ? Float.valueOf(stringFloat) / hundred
           : zero;  // sonar showing issue in this statement
    floatList.add(value);
}
```

Comment: "sonar showing issue in this statement" Every expression in that statement of type `Float` should be a `float`: `Float.valueOf(stringFloat) => Float.parseFloat(...)`, `Float hundred => float hundred`, `Float zero => float zero`. But also, there's little point in defining variables with easily-understood values: just use `100F` instead of `hundred` etc.

Comment: Actually, I implemented float instead of Float earlier it self. but still issue is not resolving. So, I thought I should use Float only because If I use float then again autoboxing will happen to store the result into value variable. so I converted that statement to Float values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<>();
float hundred = 100F;
float zero = 0F;
String[] stringFloatValues = new String[]{"1.2", "3.44", "5.66"};

for (String stringFloat: stringFloatValues) {
    float value = NumberUtils.isParsable(stringFloat)
           ? Float.parseFloat(stringFloat) / hundred
           : zero;  // sonar showing issue in this statement
    floatList.add(value);
}
```

As you calculate, do a division (`/`), keep everything as primitive type `float`.
`Float.valueOf` would give a boxed Float, which would need to be unboxed to float, as also `hundred`. As above - with `parseFloat`giving a float -, the resulting float `value` will be boxed on `add`.